# How to share video on Facebook

Tags: iphone, facebook-graph-api, ios5

I'm developing an IPhone app where I have added videos. I would like to share that videos on Facebook. I have added FbGraphAPI. I don't know how to should I share video.

I have added FbGraphAPI from here https://github.com/reallylongaddress/iPhone-Facebook-Graph-API

Thanks

Comment: I have found this; http://developers.facebook.com/blog/post/2011/08/04/how-to--use-the-graph-api-to-upload-a-video--ios/